# set and clear background image of html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to customize this button that loads a background image in from the user input. Once they have added a background image, when they go to add another image (i.e. click Choose the second time), I want the first one to be removed from the background when the prompt re-opens to add another.

```js
$(switchBackground);
    var oFReader = new FileReader(),
        rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

    oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
        localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
        switchBackground();
    };

    function switchBackground() {
      $('body').css('background-image', "url(" + localStorage.getItem('b') + ')');    
    }

    function loadImageFile(testEl) {
      if (! testEl.files.length) { return; }
      var oFile = testEl.files[0];
      if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
      oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
    }
```

```html
<input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" />
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle of this code.](http://jsfiddle.net/tc3r4sj5/)

Comment: It works in JS Fiddle? Do you mean when they click choose it removes any background image, regardless of whether they select another one or not?

Comment: yes ..when clicking it for the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add a click listener to the same input, which means whenever the user clicks anywhere inside the input it will call to empty the background. In your JS Fiddle, it is setting the background on the body, so I'll go with that in this example: -

```
function emptyBg() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'none';
}
```

Register the click event (using the same syntax you used - although this should be attached using JavaScript and not HTML, see [DOM Event Listeners](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)).

```
<input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" onclick="emptyBg()"/>
```

Comment: Great! Be sure to accept the answer (little grey tick on the left of the answer) if you are happy this has resolved your issue. Thanks!